# Don't understand the date format in mysql like 1286066935 - UserCake

Tags: mysql, date, usercake

I'am using [`UserCake`](http://www.usercake.com/) for UserManagement - in the table `userCake_Users` there is a column `LastSignIn` but the value is in this format: 1286066935

with this function I get the right Date

```
public function updateLastSignIn()
{
    global $db,$db_table_prefix;

    $sql = "UPDATE ".$db_table_prefix."Users
            SET
            LastSignIn = '".time()."'
            WHERE
            User_ID = '".$db->sql_escape($this->user_id)."'";

    return ($db->sql_query($sql));
}
```

but which format is 1286066935?

this is the sql file

```
--
-- Table structure for table `Users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (
  `User_ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Username` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Username_Clean` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ActivationToken` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `LastActivationRequest` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LostPasswordRequest` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Active` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `Group_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SignUpDate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LastSignIn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`User_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: It's not really MySQL's issue, but how your PHP script was designed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is it's a [UNIX Timestamp](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm).

Comment: ok thank you, great! is this format good? or should I convert it to another format? I will accept your answer in 10 minutes. thanks

Comment: It's a widely used format.  But typically in a DB you'd use a DATETIME column instead of the raw INT value (even though it can be represented as an INT just fine)

Comment: FWIW, the UNIX timestamp format is not good for dates past 2038-01-19.  I recommend using DATETIME too.

Comment: The advantage of using a timestamp is you don't have to worry about what your database or data access layer is going to do with date formatting and timezones. You can of course use a larger integer type to get a longer range of values.

Answer (score 2):

> but which format is 1286066935?

It's [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). It's the number of seconds since midnight GMT on 1st January 1970.

1286066935 represents 00:48:55 GMT today, 3rd October 2010.

You can convert a Unix timestamp to an 'ordinary' date/time using an online converter like [this one](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm). Alternatively you can use the `date` command, on Linux:

```
$ date -d @1286066935
Sun Oct  3 01:48:55 BST 2010
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called a [Unix Time Stamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Basically, in Unix time stamps are represented as the number of seconds from the [Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) or Jan 1, 1970

Answer (score 1):

It's UNIX time: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

The time()-function in php (assuming that's what you're using) returns the time in the very same format, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a UNIX timestamp to me (number of seconds since 1st January 1970.)

Assuming you're using PHP based on that code snippet, you can use the `time()` function to return the current UNIX timestamp for insertion into your database.

If you wanted to do the processing with your MySQL query, take a look at the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Probably UNIX time. Number of seconds since 01/01/1970.